# How do I get the exception that caused a Persist action to fail?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have a standard WCF service workflow with several Persist actions (all created via UI drag and drop). Most of the persist actions succeed, but one fails.

Wrapping the failing Persist action in a Try/Catch block does not help - it just steps over the catch and terminates the workflow.

How do I find the specific reason why the persist failed? Is any exception logged anywhere?

I'm developing on Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the specific details of the underlying error, run the workflow in debug mode (or attach to w3wp.exe). In Visual Studio, make sure that the "Just My Code" option is NOT enabled in Debug > Options and Settings and make sure you enable Debug > Exceptions > Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Then the IDE will give you the error when you step through.

Thing is - you can't do this on a production server, so not sure how you would get detailed error information in production, if only a high level message is given in the tracking event.

Comment: This post refers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/dublin/thread/51c86bc4-c2ff-4627-a128-4be701b77568?prof=required

Answer (score 7):

I log the exception in a file adding a listener to the System.Activities.DurableInstancing namespace, you will be able to see the exception there:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Activities.DurableInstancing" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="textListener" />
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="textListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Log\persistenceproblem.txt" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Here it is explained in my blog
http://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/how-to-analyze-a-workflow-foundation-4-0-persistence-problem/

Comment: Hi, What other values apart from Verbose can be used here?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the ETWTracingParticipant should help you see the error in the Windows event log. Something that is often the problem is that some of the state is your workflow is not serializable.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. (I was guessing that there was a serialization problem somewhere, but I can't track it down. I've manually serialized all my custom types and they all work fine when I test them). I've added the behaviour <etwTracking profileName="Sample Tracking Profile" /> to my web.config (it's a WCF workflow service). But no .etl file seems to get created on my drive. (I'm on XP, so I may not be able to view them in the event log, even if they are on the drive). Is there some other bit of configuration I'm missing to turn on the tracking?

Comment: Does the profile mentioned exist? Haven't tried this using XP I am expecting the events to show up in the standard Windows Event Viewer. Otherwise create  a custom TrackingParticipant and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks. I added a custom tracking participant as you suggested, and got it logging to the database (as per the MS SQLTracking sample). That gave me a rather unhelpful error: "The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}SaveWorkflow was interrupted by an error." - logged in the WorkflowInstanceEventsTable. I then discovered how I could get the underlying error (see answer to this thread).